# BaseAdapter with search function and jsonArray

Tags: android, baseadapter

I would like to have a search function on my BaseAdapter.
Here is the code from my BaseAdapter:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by Fabi on 12.09.2015.
 */
public class GetAllMessagesListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private JSONArray dataArray;
    private Activity activity;
    private static LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;


    public GetAllMessagesListViewAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray, Activity activity) {
        this.dataArray = jsonArray;
        this.activity = activity;

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataArray.length();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ListCell cell;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.get_all_customer_list_view, null);
            cell = new ListCell();

            cell.customer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customer);

            convertView.setTag(cell);
        } else {
            cell = (ListCell) convertView.getTag();
        }

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(position);
            cell.customer.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        Filter filter = null;

        return filter;
    }

    private class ListCell {
        private TextView sender, receiver, message, customer;
    }

    //SEARCH FUNCTION
}
```

Now I want to search the displayed names of the customer from the jsonArray. Any suggestions and solutions? Thanks a lot for helping!